# Получение информации с других сайтов. Подскажите

Tags: javascript, веб-программирование, get

Добрый день!
Сразу прошу прощения за возможно глупые вопросы, сам пришел с других языков программирования, и по нужде рабочей приходится писать на JS. Не прошу разжёвывать мне как школьнику мой вопрос, мне нужен просто совет знающих людей.

Мне нужно запилить расширение под Хром.
Мне необходимо получать информацию с со страниц других сайтов.
Текстовая, графическая, ссылки на аудиофайлы. 
Принцип получения информации мне понятен, библиотека JQuery просто можно сказать делает все за вас, лишь пиши нормально код. Но не понятно как я могу получать информацию с сайтов.

Натолкните на нужную мысль, накидайте ссылок на источники, дайте совет вообще в какую степь копать.
Любая помощь в тему, будет очень полезна.

Заренее благодарен!

Comment: что подразумевается вод 'информация с других сайтов' Это данные из их DOM-элементов или их ответ на GET, POST т пр. запросы?

Answer (score 1):

Доступ и манипуляция DOM окружением интересующей страницы через расширение хрома это все через content script.

https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts